# Set font and tooltip to dynamically created contextmenustrip item

Tags: vb.net

With few static `contextmenustrip` items I create additional items from database dynamically like this:

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If reader.HasRows Then Arh_ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("-", Nothing, Nothing)
While (reader.Read())
    If CStr(reader.GetValue(0)).Length = 17 And Not CStr(reader.GetValue(0)) = mydatabase Then
        Arh_ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(CStr(reader.GetValue(0)), Nothing, AddressOf myHandler_Click)
        'How to set font "Courier New" for this item?
        'How to set tooltip for this item?
    End If
End While
```

Question is: can I and how to set different font like "Courier New" for such items and add tooltip text for every such item. That's because I will need proportional font for those items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out,

```
While (reader.Read())

     If CStr(reader.GetValue(0)).Length = 17 And Not CStr(reader.GetValue(0)) _
     = mydatabase Then

        'Adding item into a context menu strip will return the same.
        Dim xAddedItem = Arh_ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add(CStr(reader.GetValue(0)), _
        Nothing,AddressOf myHandler_Click)

        'Set Different fonts matching your requirement
        xAddedItem .Font = New Font("Courier New", 14, FontStyle.Bold)
        xAddedItem .ToolTipText = "Hello I'm the tool tip"

    End If

End While
```